# Issue with dojox.mobile.TextBox in Android app using PhoneGap

Tags: android, dojo, cordova

I'm have trouble using the widget dojox.mobile.TextBox in my Android app.
Here is the simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojox/mobile/themes/custom/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">

    <div>
        <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" placeHolder="Enter LAST name" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        // Load the widget parser and mobile base
        require([
        "dojox/mobile/parser",
        "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
        "dojox/mobile/compat",
        "dojox/mobile",
        "dojox/mobile/TextBox"
        ], function(parser, deviceTheme) {
            // Parse the page for widgets!
            parser.parse();
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is the error I get:

```
06-04 15:22:52.304: E/Web Console(28791): Uncaught Error: declare dojox.mobile.TextBox: mixin #1 is unknown. Did you use dojo.require to pull it in? at file:///android_asset/www/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:15
```

I also tried with dojox.mobile.app.TextBox but then I get:

```
06-04 15:46:16.192: E/Web Console(29566): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dynamic' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:15
```

I made sure I have the last version of dojo.
If anybody has an answer it would really help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by moving:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    // Load the widget parser and mobile base
    require([
    "dojox/mobile/parser",
    "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
    "dojox/mobile/compat",
    "dojox/mobile",
    "dojox/mobile/TextBox"
    ], function(parser, deviceTheme) {
        // Parse the page for widgets!
        parser.parse();
        });
```

into the head tag area and add "dojo/domReady!" to you dojo require block.  You should probably add another thing in the head to configure dojo properly:

```
<script>dojoConfig = {
async: true,
parseOnLoad: true
}
</script>
```

You should study all the examples located here:
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.0/dojo-release-1.9.0/dojox/mobile/tests/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I moved the requires into the head and don't have the errors anymore. Even though, I'm not sure that the TextBox is correctly displayed as it does not have a paticular style.

Comment: If you mean that you would like to use a different theme, check out http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/themes.html  You are probably seeing the default theme for mobile.